# How to Access Cursor Columns Without FETCH .. INTO

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-cursor

I'm using SQL Server to build stored procedures, and I'm using cursors to loop through a select statement

I'm defining the cursor as follow:

```
DECLARE @c_col1 varchar(max);
DECLARE @c_col2 varchar(max);

DECLARE c as CURSOR FOR 
SELECT col1, col2 
FROM table;

OPEN c;
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO
@c_col1, @c_col2;

SELECT @c_col1, @c_col2;
```

Is there a way to access the columns of the cursor without a need to declare variables for each column and to use INTO in FETCH clause? In other words, is it possible to use:

```
DECLARE c as CURSOR FOR 
SELECT col1, col2 
FROM table;

OPEN c;
FETCH NEXT FROM c; 

SELECT c.col1, c.col2;
```

Comment: Why do you need to use cursors? You should really try and find a set based alternative using SQL as this is what databases are good at processing. Often cursor code is much much slower than the equivalent SQL.

Comment: @pjp, sometimes cursors are useful to run some complex logic on a row-by-row basis, often by calling a stored procedure for each row returned.  Also, if you need to do something like delete a few million rows, a single set-based query can lock up your database for a long time.  Deleting one row at a time with a cursor takes a lot longer but allows the database to breathe while it's happening.

Comment: you can loop and process data, without a cursor.  You can get massive performance improvements replacing cursors with set based operations.  However, I have replaced the use of cursors, but still looped (because it was really necessary) and have still seen big performance gains.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are after, but your code is not typical, and you certainly do not have to do it that way, as the selected answer says.

Comment: @Eric Z Beard, this exactly when I would never use a cursor. I'd process in batches using a while loop. Much faster to delete 10000 records at a time in a loop than run row-by-agonizing-row in a cursor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you have to do it that way if you want to store the values from the cursor in local variables instead of returning them back to the client.

Comment: from the OP's code, they are returning the values as a 1 row reslt set of two columns

Answer (score 0):

if this is your entire porcedure (right from OP question):

```
DECLARE @c_col1 varchar(max);
DECLARE @c_col2 varchar(max);

DECLARE c as CURSOR FOR 
SELECT col1, col2 
FROM table;

OPEN c;
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO
@c_col1, @c_col2;

SELECT @c_col1, @c_col2;
```

then you can just do the following to return a result set of the two columns, no cursor necessary:

```
SELECT top 1 col1, col2 
FROM table;
```