# SQL statement for loop through table and insert into another

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop

I try to loop through a table and insert each row into antoher.

Statement:

```
SELECT firstname FROM importliste_3
OPEN rotate;
FETCH NEXT FROM rotate;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
      --print firstname
      FETCH NEXT FROM rotate;
   END;
CLOSE rotate;
DEALLOCATE rotate;
GO
```

How can I access the firstname from the current selected row. I need a variable of the current firstname for an insert into different tables with primary and foreign keys.

I use the SQL Server 2008.

Comment: If you *really* have to use a cursor use `INTO [variable list]`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298487/how-to-access-cursor-columns-without-fetch-into

Comment: Is importliste_3 a staging table?

Comment: yes, imported it from a csv.

Answer (score 1):

> Before I insert something, I want to test it with a print.

Why?  It's MUCH more efficient to just do it in one set operation:

```
INSERT INTO (destination)
SELECT (columns) from (sourcetable)
```

Turning that into a cursor simply to print each value for debugging purpose is a waste.

Comment: yes, but I need to insert much more data into different tables with primary and foreign keys. That was a basic example. The firstname and lastname need an insert into (example) persons, the ID generates an autoinc. I scope the latest ID and insert this into a second table with this ID as foreign key.

Comment: @mnlfischer OK that makes more sense.  You can still do that with set operations if you are using SQL 2005 or later.  I would add the _real_ reason you want to loop to your question and specify which version of SQL server you are using.

Comment: And if you really need to know which rows were inserted, check out the [`OUTPUT` clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) present in SQL Server **2005** and newer....